# android webview Related

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I have multiple html files which i saved in the assets folder. one of my html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .outer{width:300px; height:460px; padding:10px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="outer">
    <h4 style="text-align:right; margin-bottom:30px; width:300px;"><a href="#0">HOME</a></h4>
    <h1>World Map -01</h1>
    <img src="world_map.png" width="300" alt="" />
    <h4 style="text-align:right; margin-top:30px; width:300px;"><a href="#2">NEXT</a></h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

there is 3 more html file is as same as this. 
The first page will loads. here I want to get the href and load the links manually by checking the href.

My code is:

```
public class WebvwActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
}
}
```

**What i want to do for fetching the href value and load the links by checking the href value??**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webview's WebViewClient for this. There is a function [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) which can be used to detect the href value and can be acted upon accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of these ways to run it the normal way:

```
<li><a href="testing2.html" data-transition="none" rel="external">testing2</a></li>
```

and put your  testing2.html file in www folder

Comment: i dont want to edit in the html part.. I need coding for getting the href value and to load the links..

Comment: I want to run the program manually by getting the href value and according to the href value only they will load to next page.